# Replace element with outerHTML and immediately access the newly created element

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am replacing a DOM element by replacing its content with `outerHTML`. The trick works, but I need to immediately access the DOM element that was newly created.

Unfortunately the creation of element `<x>` and generation of the contents of `var code` is not under my control.

```js
var code, e;

(function () {
  /**
   * Things done inside this IIFE is not under my control
   */
  code =
    '<div style="border: 1px solid black;">' +
    '  <span>I </span>' +
    '  <span>want </span>' +
    '  <span>to </span>' +
    '  <span>access </span>' +
    '  <span>all </span>' +
    '  <span>these </span>' +
    '  <span>spans.</span>' +
    '</div>';
  e = document.getElementById('replace_this');
}());

e.outerHTML = code;

// by this point, element e is replaced with newly added HTML. Let's do
// an alert to make sure
alert('Check the document. New HTML is rendered.');

var spans = e.getElementsByTagName('span'); // oops! empty collection
alert(spans.length); // alerts 0
alert(e.outerHTML); // alerts '<x></x>'
```

```html
<div id="container" style="padding: 20px; border: 1px dashed grey;">
  <div>Don't replace this.</div>
  <x id="replace_this"></x>
  <div>Don't replace this either.</div>
</div>
```

The behavior is explained in [MDN's notes on `outerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML#Notes):

> Also, while the element will be replaced in the document, the variable whose outerHTML property was set will still hold a reference to the original element

So my question is, how can I access the newly added elements immediately after I replaced the old element?

PS: I am ready to abandon `outerHTML` if there's another way that I can use to replace an element and then access the newly created element.

Comment: You won't be able to, because you've effectively deleted the parent element `e`. The object still remains with an old copy of the HTML. You can trick it by applying `code` to `e.innerHTML`, then you set `e.outerHTML = e.innerHTML`, but again this is operating off a now non-existent list of nodes. I would not suggest this method as it may function differently in different browsers.

Comment: I have no trouble accessing it using your code plus: var target = document.getElementById('container');
alert(elementChildren(target)[0].children.length);

for (var i = 0; i < elementChildren(target)[0].children.length; i++) {
    elementChildren(target)[0].children[i].style.border = '1px red solid';
    alert(elementChildren(target)[0].children[i].innerHTML);
}

Comment: Is this not what you are looking for?

Comment: @AlphaG33k: That won't generalize. It will work until element `#container` has only one child. This is not the case with me. Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Finally I settled for inserting the new element *before*, using [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML), getting the new element by calling [`previousSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/previousSibling), and then removing the unnecessary element with [`parentElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentElement)`.`[`removeChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild)

```js
var code, e;

(function () {
  /**
   * Things done inside this IIFE is not under my control
   */
  code =
    '<div style="border: 1px solid black;">' +
    '  <span>I </span>' +
    '  <span>want </span>' +
    '  <span>to </span>' +
    '  <span>access </span>' +
    '  <span>all </span>' +
    '  <span>these </span>' +
    '  <span>spans.</span>' +
    '</div>';
  e = document.getElementById('replace_this');
}());

// insert the new element just before <x>
e.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeBegin', code);
// now <x>'s previousSibling should be the newly added element
var new_elem = e.previousSibling;
// get rid of <x>
e.parentElement.removeChild(e);

// by this point, element e is replaced with newly added HTML. Let's do
// an alert to make sure
alert('Check the document. New HTML is rendered.');

var spans = new_elem.getElementsByTagName('span'); 
alert(spans.length); // alerts 7
alert(new_elem.outerHTML); // alerts contents of new element
```

```html
<div id="container" style="padding: 20px; border: 1px dashed grey;">
  <div>Don't replace this.</div>
  <x id="replace_this"></x>
  <div>Don't replace this either.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use `previousElementSibling` in case the inserted HTML has trailing whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

Why not give the generated div an id? You could then getElementById on the new element.

eg.

```
var code =
    '<div id="newElement" style="border: 1px solid black;">' +
    '  <span>I </span>' +
    '  <span>want </span>' +
    '  <span>to </span>' +
    '  <span>access </span>' +
    '  <span>all </span>' +
    '  <span>these </span>' +
    '  <span>spans.</span>' +
    '</div>';

var e = document.createElement('x');
document.getElementById('container').appendChild(e);
e.outerHTML = code;

// by this point, element e is replaced with newly added HTML. Let's do
// an alert to make sure
alert('Check the document. New HTML is rendered.');

e = getElementById('newElement'); // reassign e to the new div
var spans = e.getElementsByTagName('span'); 
alert(spans.length);
alert(e.outerHTML);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately the part where element is created and part where the code-to-be-inserted is generated is not under my control. Should have included this info in the question. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get it fine using the following javascript:

```js
var code =
    '<div style="border: 1px solid black;">' +
    '  <span>I </span>' +
    '  <span>want </span>' +
    '  <span>to </span>' +
    '  <span>access </span>' +
    '  <span>all </span>' +
    '  <span>these </span>' +
    '  <span>spans.</span>' +
    '</div>';

var e = document.createElement('x');

document.getElementById('container').appendChild(e);

e.outerHTML = code;

var spans = e.getElementsByTagName('span'); // oops! empty collection
```

These are my changes:

```
/**
 * Return direct children elements.
 *
 * @param {HTMLElement}
 * @return {Array}
 */
function elementChildren(element) {
    var childNodes = element.childNodes,
        children = [],
        i = childNodes.length;

    while (i--) {
        if (childNodes[i].nodeType == 1) {
            children.unshift(childNodes[i]);
        }
    }

    return children;
}
var target = document.getElementById('container');
alert(elementChildren(target)[0].children.length);

for (var i = 0; i < elementChildren(target)[0].children.length; i++) {
    elementChildren(target)[0].children[i].style.border = '1px red solid';
    alert(elementChildren(target)[0].children[i].innerHTML);
}

<div id="container" style="padding: 20px; border: 1px dashed grey;"></div>
```

Here is a Codepen with the code so you can edit play around with it: http://codepen.io/nicholasabrams/pen/VLGMgj

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but wouldn't this fail if element `#container` had other children other than `<x>`?

Comment: @Krumia if you update your code in the OP to show a new issue I will attempt to resolve that as well, however I need to see the issue demonstrated

Comment: (I found [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31556230/1461424) that suits *me* on my own. But wanted to let you know about the clarifications I made on the question). I wanted element `#container` to have other children other than `<x>` (Updated in my answer). So unfortunately this breaks as you can see in [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7dn1p6ex/). Also, the element is returned from a function I cannot modify. Sorry for changing the rules after getting answers.