# In Javascript, why does setting outerHTML on an element set its parentNode to 'null'?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

In Javascript, when I set the outerHTML of an element in the DOM to a new value (to change it into a different element, for example), its 'parentNode' property gets set to 'null'. Why? I would expect it to remain at whatever value it was at before the outerHTML change.

I guess that the DOM is creating a new object from parsing the 'outerHTML' string and using it to replace the original object. If this is the case, is there a method to retrieve that newly created object?

Steps to reproduce (tested on Linux Chrome & Linux Firefox)

1. Open a clean window in your browser,
2. Open the dev console (F12, probably)
3. Take a look at the page DOM (Element tab in Chrome, Inspector in Firefox)
4. Delete any children of the 'body', just to make things cleaner
5. Open the console and type:

   `obj1 = document.createElement('div')`

   `obj1.id = '1'`

   `document.body.appendChild(obj1);`

   `obj1.parentNode` - Should write the 'body' HTML to the console.

   `obj1.outerHTML = "<div id='2'></div>"`

   `obj1.parentNode` - Now writes 'null' to the console.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31550944/1461424

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is as per [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML#Notes)

> Also, while the element will be replaced in the document, the variable
>   whose outerHTML property was set will still hold a reference to the
>   original element:

which means `obj1` in your code is still referring to original element which has been detached from the DOM tree by now.